# Where Condition SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, conditional-statements

I need to put a condition to get only cp7 (ZIPCode) where street are not null

```
select top 1 cp7 
from codigospostais 
order by newid()
```

I have tried to add a where condition, but it did not worked (incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where)':

```
where street is not null
```

Can you help to find the right way to constrain this?

Thank you

Comment: You can not write 'where' after order by clause. Please try to learn sql first. this is not learning site.

Answer (score 4):

```
select top 1 cp7 
from codigospostais 
where street is not null
order by newid()
```

Answer (score 2):

It has to come after the `from` section and before the `order by` section:

```
select top 1 cp7 from codigospostais where street is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

you can not use where after order by clause, try this

```
 SELECT top 1 cp7 FROM codigospostais WHERE ISNULL(street,'') <> '' ORDER BY NEWID()
```